# Is Java (de-)serialization atomic?

Tags: java, serialization, persistence, atomic, objectinputstream

For this question it is assumed that the serialization/deserialization is atomic when the object is either written entirely to stream and read out successfully, or when an object is partially written to stream and an exception occurs when the object is read back. It is assumed that the write operation may not complete successfully, e.g. because of a power outage.

In the description of the [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) class I read that:

> This may also occur if the serialization stream has been tampered; hence, `readObjectNoData` is useful for initializing deserialized objects properly despite a "hostile" or incomplete source stream.

This *could* hint to the fact that reading objects from an `ObjectInputStream` is not atomic. Does that mean that reading Java objects from a stream may not be an atomic operation?

Am I certain that an exception is thrown if a partial object was written to persistent memory and then retrieved?

If Java serialization is non-atomic, are there any best practices of (de-)serializing objects to persistent memory as an atomic operation?

---

Notes:

- I'm not considering serialization to a database (e.g. using Hibernate) here; with persistent storage I mean for instance using `ObjectInputStream` and `FileInputStream`;
- with atomic I mean for instance what happens during the reading of objects after a power loss occured when they were written do disk;
- I'm not using multithreading to read or write objects from a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This could hint to the fact that reading objects from an ObjectInputStream is not atomic. Does that mean that reading Java objects from a stream may not be an atomic operation?

I'm not aware of any statement anywhere that it *is* atomic in the sense you mean, but I also don't see what it has to do with the excerpt you cited. Reading an object involves quite a few read operations: the tag, the class name, and all the fields, and it is therefore impossible for the overall operation to be atomic in the sense you seem to mean.

> Am I certain that an exception is thrown if a partial object was written to persistent memory and then retrieved?

I don't see how you could avoid getting an exception.

> If Java serialization is non-atomic, are there any best practices of serializing objects to persistent memory as an atomic operation?

You can't ensure it happens, but you can catch the exceptions that are thrown if it doesn't. Call `flush()`, and if it fails you have an incomplete serialization.

> with atomic I mean for instance what happens during power loss when writing to disk

Writes of objects to disk are not atomic either. They consist of several logical writes. If your program gets stopped because of the power outage and so doesn't even get the `IOException`, all you have is a short file that will cause exceptions when read.

Comment: OK, so there will be an exception for sure if part of the object encoding is missing, in that case? I presume that may not be the case for objects that sport custom encodings / arrays?

Comment: Wait a second, I'm being stupid. If it cannot know when the data ends, it cannot distinguish between one object to another. So the format of the object must contain a well defined end.

Comment: There are length words in the protocol, tags that say 'this is an `int,` etc.